# Fixing textarea problems in mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="f">
  <h3>Got a question? Post here for discussion!</h3>
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Write a Title..." size="82" required="required" />
  <br/>
  <textarea cols="83" rows="4" name="content" placeholder="Write description..." required="required"></textarea>
  <br /> 
  <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Post to Timeline" />
</form>
```

When I run the code above in Google Chrome, the length of the textarea and the input type="text" are the same but in mozilla firefox the the textarea becomes longer than the formal. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try specifying the width and height using CSS instead of the html?

```
textarea {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

See if that makes a difference. You can change the pixels if needed. I just chose something close.

Comment: No problem! Glad that I could help! @S.ANYIMAH

Answer (score 1):

That's because:

- `size` and `cols` specify a number of characters, not a length. But the width of the characters depends on the font, and `input` and `textarea` use different fonts by default. Specify a common font to prevent this.
- `textarea` can overflow, and then it reserves some additional space in case it needs scrollbars. Use `overflow: hidden` to prevent this.

```css
input, textarea {
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="f">
  <h3>Got a question? Post here for discussion!</h3>
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Write a Title..." size="32" required="required" />
  <br/>
  <textarea cols="32" rows="4" name="content" placeholder="Write description..." required="required"></textarea>
  <br /> 
  <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Post to Timeline" />
</form>
```

That said, you might prefer using the CSS `width` property instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `cols` and `rows` attributes. Use CSS `width` and `height` properties to ensure a consistent experience across browsers.